# Is there a difference between using a type filter vs specifying doc_type in the url/api?

Tags: elasticsearch

The title says it all: Is there a difference between using a type filter(s) vs specifying doc_type(s) in the url/api, ie

```
...
"filter" : {
    'type': {
        'value': 'my_doc_type'
    }
}
....
```

vs

```
GET /my_index/my_doc_type/_search
```

**EDIT**:
I meant as a *filter* in a *filtered* query; however, I'm going to leave the question as is, so that there's more information to be gleaned from the responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Specifying the type in the URL will apply **before** the query is run.

Specifying the type as a filter will apply **after** the query is run.

As a side note, using a filtered query instead of a filter will function similarly to specifying the type in the URL, as it will apply **before** the query is run.

Do be careful with the functionality of Filters vs Filtered queries if you are using facets as they function differently on facets.

Filtered query:

```
{
  "query":{
    "filtered":{
      "query":{
        "term":{"name":"franky"}
      },
      "filter":{
        "term":{"age":73}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Filter:

```
{
  "query":{
    "term":{"name":"franky"}
  },
  "filter":{
    "term":{"age":73}
  }
}
```

Comment: I made an edit in response to your comment.  I did indeed mean a filter inside of a filtered query... Are you certain that the behavior is the same for filtered/url?  If so, how?

Comment: I'm afraid it's no longer clear. I can tell you that in an earlier version (which I no longer remember) kimchy (one of ES creators) stated that specifying type via the URL actually creates a filter exactly like filtered queries, one that is applied before the actual query is run. I tried to find the thread but failed unfortunately. I can not vouch for newer version of ES. I can state that describing types in the URL is generally considered better practice, mostly because feedback from Imotov/Kimchy etc. generally utilize that syntax. But that's anecdotal and flimsy evidence. Sorry =(